# interfacing ROS and arduino

Tags: arduino, ros

## BACKSTORY

The other day I found a motorized wheel chair that someone was throwing away. Being a maker who spends a lot of time looking at what other people have made online I decided to snatch it and try to make a robot out of it. I also bought an Arduino mega, a Kinect sensor, and a motor controller to try to control the motors and give it some form of vision.

## MY VISION

Honestly I don’t intend for this robot to be much more than a fun, and challenging, project. My current goals are to have it run SLAM algorithms to figure out where it is on a map and for it to navigate to predetermined points on the map. However at this point I would be happy with just being able to do a simple teleop control with the keyboard.

## MY PROBLEM

I have spent the past week researching ros and how to get it talking to my Arduino. I have installed [diff_drive_controller](http://wiki.ros.org/diff_drive_controller?distro=indigo), [Turtlebot](http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot), [ros_control](http://wiki.ros.org/ros_control), [ros_serial](http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial_arduino), [ros_arduino_bridge](http://wiki.ros.org/ros_arduino_bridge), and several others trying to find something that will tell the motors what to do. By now I feel like I have a good barely below the surface understanding about how ros works. Basically there are a series of nodes each publishing info for the other nodes to see and subscribing to info that they want to read. All I want right now is a node that publishes data about the velocity of the motors based on it trying to navigate or teleop or something like that. I think turtlebot is my best bet considering it is an all in one stack that does everything I want it to do. The only problem is I don’t have an iRobot create. But it seems like it should be simple enough to intercept those commands and have them drive my own robot base. However I’m not sure which topic to listen on and how to run turtle bot in a way that doesn’t try to connect to an iRobot create. I could just listen to the /cmd_vel_mux/input/teleop topic but I think that would limit me to just teleop and it might make it hard to move on to autonomy in the future.

What topic should I listen on? Am I going about this the right way? Are there any packages that would be better suited for my needs? Keep in mind that I am new to ros so tutorials would be appreciated.

I look forward to your responses

Thanks, Logan

Comment: Do you really need ROS? Besides, why not ask on [Robotics Stackexchange](http://robotics.stackexchange.com)?

Comment: well honestly i didn't know there was a Robotics Stackexchange. and what would you recommend i use other than ros to create an autonomous robot?

Comment: There are some Arduino SLAM implementations without ROS -  honestly ROS is a huge mess most of the time, sometimes even tutorials won't work and the documentation is not always updated. Just my subjective impression :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nice sounding project! I second the recommendation to take a look at the tutorials, but I think you spend some more time with the basic [ROS tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials) before diving into the world of Arduino + ROS.

For instance, I noticed one misconception I believe you may have. It doesn't really matter which topic your nodes listens to, as its just a name that can be easily remapped through a parameter given when launching the node. The important thing is to ensure you are listening to the right *type* of messages - they specify the interface by which all the different nodes communicate. There's a [bunch of options](http://wiki.ros.org/common_msgs), and if none of them fit your use case, you can define your own.

I suspect that for low-level things, such as drivers for your motors, you will need to write your own ROS nodes. For advanced functionality, such as SLAM; there's a variety of options. You can find one that's suited to the input data you have available from your sensors.

One last recommendation is to take advantage of the features of ROS that allow you to break a big problem into manageable subtasks. Do one thing at a time - implement a motor contoroller, write a teleoperation method; taking care to specify suitable interfaces at each point. The advantage of this approach is that if you made smart choices in defining individual components with good interfaces, it is very easy to replace them with another one should you so wish.

Comment: so let me get this straight, instead of subscribing to topics like `/cmd/vel` i should just subscribe to all `turtle_actionlib/velocity` messages in general. if so how can i echo that to the terminal in order to see what is going on and maybe investigate the output of some messages.

Comment: @Logan Not familiar with that message type but basically yes. The important thing is to make sure the type of message fits what your motor driver is expecting as input. For instance, [`geometry_msgs/Twist`](http://docs.ros.org/api/geometry_msgs/html/msg/Twist.html) is typical for velocity control. You can echo anything that's going on on whatever topic using the [`rostopic`](http://wiki.ros.org/rostopic) command line tool with the `echo` option. Also, [`rosmsg`](http://wiki.ros.org/rosmsg) allows you to examine messages further.

Answer (score 1):

You can find a list of tutorials how to interface Arduino and ROS [here.](http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial_arduino/Tutorials)